# how to change default user profile address in osqa

Tags: python, osqa

I'm developing a web based program in which I want to use osqa as a question and answer module. I no longer need osqa profile, so I want to redirect users to another address. 
Now the url profile in osqa is something like [this](http://www.hamcodi.ir/qa/users/8/hamedkh) and I want to change it to [this](http://www.hamcodi.ir/members/8/hamedkh) instead. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to show user profile from your web based program instead of OSQA profile right?

The most simple way I see to do that is redirect the user from the proper Django view.
On forum/views/users.py go to line 340 which is the user_profile view. There make the first lines of the method like this:

```
profileUrl = 'http://www.hamcodi.ir/members/' + str(user.id) + '/' + user.username + '/'
return HttpResponseRedirect(profileUrl)
```

Then do the proper handling on your program.